# Converting nchar to a char

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to compare a varchar to an nchar which is stored in the datadase. I have the code below but it is not returning any records (it should return one record based on PONumber). Can someone help? The QDVR01 also has trailing spaces in it which makes up 25 characters.

```
declare @PONumber varchar(20)
set @PONumber = 'SR0173156'

select * from TESTDTA.F5942005 WHERE convert(char(25),QDVR01) like '%' + @PONumber + '%'
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong...  swap `char(25)` and `QDVR01` in the call to convert.  Otherwise, it works for me - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a981b/1

Comment: I changed it around and got this error:

Comment: Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Type QDVR01 is not a defined system type.

Comment: Im pretty sure the syntax was right.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL?  That error message looks like it's coming from SQL Server.  Here's another fiddle for SQL Server showing that it works - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a981b/2 .  Most probably the problem is with your data.

Comment: Agree with @PinnyM that this is a SQL Server error message. Sure you don't have the parameters the wrong way round? `convert(QDVR01,char(25))` would give that.

Comment: @MartinSmith - that was because the OP was trying my recommendation (which was to conform with MySQL syntax), and apparently MySQL is not in use here...

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you get rid of the trailing spaces on QDVR01.

```
select * from TESTDTA.F5942005 WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(QDVR01)) like '%' + @PONumber + '%'
```